# running windows Comman_Prompt command through package.json scripts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, command-line, package.json

I need to run in command line (cmd)

> npm run build

and after that, I need to run

> xcopy C:\fileOne C:\fileTwo

BUT, I would like to run only one command and to execute both of those above.
So I thought maybe my *package.json* should look like this:

```
 "scripts": {
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "copy": "xcopy C:\path\firstFile C:\path\secondFile",
       "zack": "npm run build && npm run copy",
 },
```

based on this idea:

```
"scripts": {
       "a1": "command1",
       "a2": "command2",
       "zack": "npm run a1 && npm run a2",
 },
```

and then I could run in command line:

> npm run zack

but I'm not managing to make it happen

(the reason why I'm doing this, is: I want to change source code in SubliteText 3 (HTML JS CSS) and automatically to send (copy-paste) in Eclipse (in some other project) )

I want to do this:

[image]

My main problem is how to put local directory path inside the string in package.json file.

Comment: If the answer below helps you out please be sure to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing commands directly inside the package.json you should write a script file that handles it for you.

Something like

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream('PATH_TO_FILE_ONE').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('PATH_TO_NEW_FILE'));
```

save the above script as something like `afterBuild.js`

and in your package.json just do zack as `npm run build && node afterBuild.js`

Comment: ok looks interesting, I tried, and when I run: **npm run build && node afterBuild.js**
I'm getting:
*Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'C:\Users\Dev30\Desktop\demo2\src\main\webapp'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE*

Comment: createReadStream is for *files* the EISDIR (Error, is directory) error means you're trying to read a directory with a command meant only to read a file. If you wish to copy an entire directory, use: ncp https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp

Answer (score 0):

I installed npc module:

> npm install ncp -g
>
> npm install ncp --save

then I created a file: *afterBuild.js* and I inserted this code inside:

```
var ncp = require("ncp");
ncp("C:/directory/file.txt", "C:/destination/directory/file.txt", callback);
function callback(){} //empty function, I don't need it for the start
```

and in *package.json* i wrote:

```
 "scripts": {
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "zack": "npm run build && node afterBuild.js"
 },
```

and I run it form command line like:

> npm run zack